# why does both my debug and release flutter apps crash milliseconds after starting?The debug worked fine before i attempted to release the app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Both my debug and release flutter apps crash milliseconds after starting, the debug worked fine before i attempted to release the app.i changed most of the items in the gradle files as required by the production process such as changing the package names from 'com.example.*' .When i open the project in android studio the gradle sync and build processes finished successfully but my app still crashes both for debug and release (after releasing again) .Solving this is quite difficult as i don't know where the error is...

This is my `flutter doctor -v` output.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.592], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at C:\Users\mutur\Desktop\new_project\flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (6 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\mutur\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\mutur\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • A37f • 6f6de11d • android-arm64 • Android 5.1.1 (API 22)

• No issues found!
```

This is my `flutter run -v` output.

```
[+3136 ms] > Configure project :app
[ +181 ms] registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
[   +1 ms] registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
[   +2 ms] registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

C:\Users\mutur\Desktop\new_project\broadcast_upgrade\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +4 ms] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="v1.0" (Raw: "v1.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="10" (Raw: "10")
               A: package="com.ClioTech.iNotify" (Raw: "com.ClioTech.iNotify")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xa
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: uses-permission (line=15)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")  
               E: uses-permission (line=16)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" (Raw: "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")
               E: uses-permission (line=17)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" (Raw:
                 "com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE")
               E: uses-permission (line=18)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" (Raw:
                 "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")
               E: application (line=26)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="iNotify" (Raw: "iNotify")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f0a0001
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw:
                 "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=32)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0c00a0
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.ClioTech.iNotify.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.ClioTech.iNotify.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x400037b4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=46)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame" (Raw:
                     "io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=50)
                     E: action (line=51)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=53)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                   E: intent-filter (line=55)
                     E: action (line=56)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" (Raw: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK")
                     E: category (line=58)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" (Raw: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
                 E: service (line=62)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" (Raw:
                   "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:directBootAware(0x01010505)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=66)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar                     " (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=69)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseAppRegi                     strar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar")     
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=72)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.FlutterFirebaseA                     ppRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=75)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistra                     r" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=78)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=81)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsC                     onnectorRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar")      
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=84)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar"   
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=87)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=90)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar" (Raw:   
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=93)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar" (Raw: 
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                 E: service (line=97)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService" (Raw:
                   "io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService")
                   E: intent-filter (line=98)
                     E: action (line=99)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT")    
                 E: provider (line=103)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" (Raw: "androidx.core.content.FileProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.ClioTech.iNotify.fileprovider" (Raw: "com.ClioTech.iNotify.fileprovider")     
                   A: android:grantUriPermissions(0x0101001b)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=108)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" (Raw: "android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS")      
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0e0000
                 E: service (line=116)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService" (Raw:
                   "com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   E: intent-filter (line=119)
                     A: android:priority(0x0101001c)=(type 0x10)0xfffffe0c
                     E: action (line=120)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT")    
                 E: receiver (line=124)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: receiver (line=129)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" (Raw: "android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES")  
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=134)
                     E: action (line=135)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" (Raw: "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER")  
                 E: service (line=139)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: service (line=143)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" (Raw: "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")  
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: receiver (line=149)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" (Raw:
                   "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=153)
                     E: action (line=154)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" (Raw:
                       "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")
                 E: activity (line=158)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity" (Raw:
                   "com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN" (Raw:        
                   "com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:excludeFromRecents(0x01010017)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x2
                 E: provider (line=166)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" (Raw:
                   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.ClioTech.iNotify.firebaseinitprovider" (Raw:
                   "com.ClioTech.iNotify.firebaseinitprovider")
                   A: android:initOrder(0x0101001a)=(type 0x10)0x64
                 E: activity (line=172)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: meta-data (line=177)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.version" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=@0x7f080004
                 E: service (line=181)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery" (Raw:       
                   "com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   E: meta-data (line=184)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="backend:com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctBackendFactory" (Raw:
                     "backend:com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctBackendFactory")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="cct" (Raw: "cct")
                 E: service (line=188)
                   A:
                   android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService"  
                   (Raw: "com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" (Raw: "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")  
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: receiver (line=194)
                   A:
                   android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.AlarmManagerSchedulerBroad                   castReceiver" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver")
```

On running without debug this is what i get

```
Launching lib\main.dart on A37f in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\mutur\Desktop\new_project\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
```

The white screen appears briefly and disappears while in the console it still says 'installing apk....'